# Laravel Passport Route returns 401 Unauthorized for public routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I am using laravel passport for authentication process.

In api.php :

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'auth',
    'middleware' => ['guest'],
], function () {
    Route::post('login', 'Api\UserController@login');   
    Route::group([
       'middleware' => 'auth:api',
    ], function () {
        Route::get('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
        Route::get('user', 'AuthController@user');
    });
});
```

and UserController.php as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function login()
    {
       dd(11111);
    }
}
```

I am testing this api with Postman which returns me 401 Unauthorized. It comes in the construct function as I tested it with print the output inside construct. But after this it start returning 401.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Change `public function login()`  instead of `public function login_user()` in your **UserController**

Comment: you have the `guest` middleware and the `auth` middleware assigned to some of these routes

Comment: @Sobir I changed it. But still it is throwing the same. Actually I was trying different things and try changing function name. In any case its throwing 401.